# Excel formula to add numbers stored as text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My NodeJS program populates an excel formula in a cell which in turn calculates the sum of all the numbers in a column. The numbers are stored as text in the cells.
The formula used is : =SUM(0+(I5:I19999)).

All the numbers are present in column 'I' but not necessarily till 19999th row (few may be blank).

However, the result of this formula is always #VALUE!.
I can't seem to find the issue in this.
Any help in this issue is really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Probably you know that this is an array formula.

Comment: @Mrig I'm fairly new to excel formula. Could you please let me know the correct formula? It would be of great help!

Comment: Formula you mentioned in the question is an array formula and need to be committed by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of just pressing `Enter`.

Comment: Formula you are trying is correct, just enter it as an array formula instead of regular formula.

Comment: @Mrig, the library I'm using currently doesn't allow me to dynamically write array formula to a excel cell. Instead do we have any regular formula to achieve this? Thanks for pointing out the issue here :)

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT((I5:I19999)*1)`

Comment: worked! Thanks a lot @Mrig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula you are using to add numbers stored as text i.e. `=SUM(0+(I5:I19999))` is an array formula and needs to be committed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want non-array formula you can use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((I5:I19999)*1)
```

Comment: This helped me so much! I was having such a hard time getting the sum of a column of numbers-formatted-as-text, but this formula did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

the value in the cell must be stored as a number because sum works on numbers only if you give text then it will display #VALUE.

you can store value as numbers using numformat('0.00').you can get more info from this page https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68.if you are reading then you have to convert it.

Could you please let me know which package(exceljs,Node-xlsx) are you using so that i can send you the code require?