# Excel SUMIFS over a range of numbers, which are formatted as strings

Tags: excel, number-formatting, sumifs

I am using an automated query in Excel, which queries TFS data from a server. This data exists in a sheet called "TFSData".
On another sheet I am running some statistic evaluations, for example counting verified stories per sprint or other gimmicks. I am Using COUNTIFS or SUMIFS formulas to get the results.

Now I am trying to use a SUMIF to get an "added value" per sprint from numbers given in the TFS Data. Here I come into trouble, because the column with the "Added value" numbers is formatted as text. 
I have no chance to manipulate this data, since the changes get lost whenever the query is rerun.

An additional helper column does not work either, because newly inserted rows after a refresh would not contain any formulas - this needs a lot of manual rework after a refresh.

The actual formula for a cell looks like this:

```
=SUMIFS(TFSData!J3:J352; TFSData!N3:N352;"*Sprint 212": TFSData!D3:D352;"Verified");
```

It produces "0" results. The "J" column is the one containing the string values, like "3", "5", etc.

I would like to use something like:

```
=SUMIFS(VALUE(TFSData!J3:J352);TFSData!N3:N352;"*Sprint 212": TFSData!D3:D352;"Verified");
```

Any ideas?

The solution looks like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TFSData!J3:J352+0;--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sprint 212";TFSData!N3:N352));--(TFSData!D3:D352="Verified"));
```

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT, e.g. as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400276/excel-formula-to-add-numbers-stored-as-text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) Use `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g.

```
= SUMPRODUCT(TFSData!J3:J352+0; (RIGHT(TFSData!N3:N352,10)="Sprint 212")+0; (TFSData!D3:D352="Verified")+0)
```

(Note the first `+0` in the formula above is to convert text to numbers, the other `+0`'s is to convert an array of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values to an array of `1`/`0` values which is necessary for `SUMPRODUCT`.)

2) Change your query to return a numeric type rather than "text that looks like numbers", then you could actually use your `SUMIFS` formula.

3) Better yet, change your query to return this sum result. That way your query returns exactly what you want instead of needing to perform an extra operation in Excel.

But I don't know the whole story, maybe options 2) and 3) aren't feasible because you're calling a stored procedure and in that case you can't alter the query. Just noting that in general I almost always find it easier to let the query perform all the work and do as little work as possible within Excel.

Comment: Only column `J` has *numbers-that-look-like-text*, so you're `+0` too many times. Also, the wildcard `*` in SUMIFS has to be a different approach in SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It worked perfectly. The only adjustment was to replace the wildcard witch a SEARCH function. =SUMPRODUCT(TFSData!J3:J352)+0;--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sprint 212";TFSData!N3:N352));--(TFSData!D3:D352="Verified"));